# How can I map Set<Date> dates without creating a new table?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Entity(name = "my_entity_name")
public class MyEntityName {

    /* some normal fields */

    private Set<Date> dates = new HashSet<>();

    /* Getters and setters for all fields */
}
```

I want to save this collection of dates as a single column (as json is ok for me) in this same entity.  Is there any solution for this in JPA?  Please help me... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use String field for that purpose.
Sets are used mostly with mapping @ManyToMany or @OneToMany

Comment: did you mean Set<String> or Set<Date> should be replaced by a String field?

Comment: I propose to use private String dates. But in general, it looks a little bit strange. Probably if you add some context to the task, i.e. what kind of classes do you have and why do you need set of dates, probably my answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using `@Converter(converter = MyCustomTypeConverter.class)` on the collection type field in my entity class.

sample converter will look like this

```
public class MyCustomTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<Date>, String> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Set<Date> attribute) {

        //code to convert from collection field to string
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Date> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {

        //code to convert from db-string field to collection field.
    }
}
```